# Elastic Beanstalk not installing yum packages from .ebextensions

Tags: amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm trying to install htop using a .ebextensions configuration file in my project root. The file is named eb.config and contains the following:

```
packages:
  yum:
    htop: []
```

yet, it doesn't get installed when I run

```
eb update
```

Is my config file wrong?

I'm using the **64bit Amazon Linux 2014.03 v1.0.3 running PHP 5.5** solution stack.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

More a question then an Answer (can't comment yet). Did you already add it to git and push it to S3? In my experience if it's not in the git zip file on S3, it doesn't get picked up.

Comment: The commit was the issue, I didn't check the .ebextensions folder in properly.

Comment: Had the same issue. Didn't realize that if git is installed, EB CLI uses the git archive command to create a .zip file from the contents of the most recent git commit command.